# PHP model structure - load attributes from database

Tags: php, database, model, load, instance

I'm currently working on a PHP script, and I'm not sure what is the best practise for the following:

Since PHP does not allow multiple constructors within a class (User), I have a constructor which has an array as argument (for the id,name,address, see code block below).

When this array does not contain an id, but is does contain other attributes (such as name, address), it calls the insert method of the class and assigns the id of the inserted row to the id attribute of the class.
When an array which does contain an id, name and address is passed to the constructor, it assigns these values to the corresponding attributes.

When I want to edit the user in the database, I can implement it in the following ways:

- Add an option to the constructor to only pass the id in the array
  (without name and address attributes, because these are not known
  when calling the update method), and than call update method on this
  instance. A problem with this is that you've got an instance which is
  not a good representation of the real object (as in the database).
  For example, you can't call the getName() method since name is not
  set.
- Same as above, but now when only the id is passed to the constructor,
  load the other attributes from the database, so that the instance is 
  a correct representation of the object as in the database. Then the
  update method can be called on this instance.
- Make the update method static, so that I can call the update method
  without making an instance

The problem with the first two points is, that I get kind of spaghetti code in my constructor since I have to check which attributes are passed to the array in the constructor.

**Which solution do you think I can choose best?**

**Do you've got a better approach which will not result in large amounts of spaghetti code in the constructor?**

```
<?php
class User
{
private $id;
private $name;
private $address;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->name = $data['name'];
    $this->address = $data['address'];

    if (isset($data['id'])) {
        $this->id = $data['id'];
    } else {
        $result = $this->insert();
        $this->id = $wpdb->insert_id; //Wordpress method for retrieving insert id
    }
}

public function get_id() { return $this->id; }
public function get_name() { return $this->name; }
public function get_address() { return $this->address; }

public function insert() { //insert into DB }
public function update($data) { //update in DB the $data attributes}
public function delete() { //delete from database }

public static function get_user_list()
{
    // load users from the database
    // foreach user {
    //      create User instance by passing the id, name and address values from the database in an array to the constructor of User
    //      add user instance to a result array
    // }
    // return result array
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method called loadUser (or something you prefer), if the data array passed to the constructor has and ID, use the loadUser method to load the details. If not, you can insert a user. After this you can move onto editing the user.